# If $ P(A) = 0 $ is $ A $ a null event?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know that $ P(\text{null event}) = 0 $, but is the reverse true? i.e. if $ P(A) = 0 $ is $ A $ a null event?

I'm not too sure I even understand what a null event is, to be honest. Could anyone give me an example of one?

Comment: no that simply means it will "almost never" happen. For example Let my sample space be all the food my mom could eat tomorrow. I could say that there is a 0 probability that my will eat vegetables tomorrow (because she never does lol) but this event is not an empty set. this is similar to idea of almost surely http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Comment: @user159813 The fact that the "event is a non empty set" does not make the event "non-null". The set of pairs of integers that sum to 13 is non-empty but it's impossible to roll 13 with two ordinary dice.

Comment: Ok I think Im getting terminology mixed up then thanks for pointing that out

Comment: That depends on whether the term "null event" refers to the empty set or to a [null set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set).

Comment: yea cause I can't really find a strict definition for it. It seems in measure theory, as the link Stefan posted also says, that a null set is a set of measure 0 thus a null event would be a one with probability 0 if it follows this definition, right?

Comment: A null set in general is a set that is contained in a measurable set with probability (or measure) zero. The null set itself need not be measurable. But I think it's unclear whether "null event" in the question refers to a null set or the empty set.

Answer (score 11):

A null event is an event that is impossible.  Or more precisely, since an event is a subset of a sample space, the null event is the empty set.  So $P(\emptyset)=0$.  However, in some situations, a nonempty event may have probability $0$.

For instance if $X$ is a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable, then $P(X=\frac12)=0$, and yet $X=\frac12$ is not an empty event.

Answer (score 1):

No.

$P(A)=0$ merely means that the probability of event A is immesurable.  It does not necessarily mean that it is impossible.

Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,1]$.  It will thus certainly not have a value outside that interval; it's impossible.  However, although it will have one value on that interval, the probability that it will have *any exact* value in that interval is almost surely zero; it can theoretically happen, but it's immesurable.

The distinction is sometimes denoted by the indicator a.s. (almost sure) or a.c. (almost certain), when you wish to be precise about why its measure zero.

$$P(X=2)=0$$
$$P(X=1/2)=0\quad\mbox{a.s.}$$

Comment: I am not sure "$P(X=1/2)=0\quad\mbox{a.s.}$" is a good example of using "almost surely".  An alternative might be to say *"$X$ is not $2$ and $X$ is almost surely not $\frac12$. Though both events have probability zero, the first is impossible while the second is only improbable."*

Answer (score 1):

If there exists an event (A), such that P(A) = 0, A is a null-event.

Null event **IS NOT** the same as an impossible event.

The best example to demonstrate this fact is the linear darts problem. Let's say, you throw a dart that falls anywhere within the interval [0,1].

$X$ $\in$ [0,1], where $X$ is the random variable that captures the position of the dart on the interval.

We know, $P(X = 1/3)$ = 0. That doesn't imply the dart falling on position (1/3) is an impossible event!

For every probabilistic experiment with a sample space $\Omega$, we can define a trivial $\sigma$-algebra that contains {$\phi$, $\Omega$}. $\phi$ is defined to be the impossible event and $P(X = \phi) = 0$.

Therefore, P(null-event) = 0 $\forall$ null-events; but P(A) = 0, implies A could either be a null-event or an impossible event($\phi$).