# Is there any concrete examples of a null event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I interpreted a line of reasoning in a book on probability, on the null set being an event of every experiment.

> Sample space are defined as a set of all possible outcomes of an experiment. Events are subsets of a sample space.

> The null set is a subset of every set. A Sample space is a set. Hence, the null set is a subset of a sample space.

> The null set is an event of any experiment.

I can not find a concrete example of a null event. Take a coin toss; would the null event be not tossing the coin at all? It does not make any sense to me. So, is there any concrete examples of a null event.

Comment: The null set is not the event that the coin is tossed, since that isn't a part of the sample space : the null set is the event that *nothing* is observed. In some sense, the sample space is the set of outcomes : so saying that the null set is a subset of a set of outcomes of an experiment , would then provide the description : "the null set event is the event that no outcome occurs at all". The sample space doesn't take into account  whether the experiment occurs or not : it only looks at what comes afterwards. For example, in a coin toss the null set is : neither heads nor tails is observed.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971855/what-is-the-difference-between-event-of-0-probability-and-null-event, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895772/if-pa-0-is-a-a-null-event, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111658/if-pa-0-is-a-a-null-event/111664.

Answer (score 0):

You want the intersection of two events to be an event, so that you can talk of the probability of A **and** B happening. And this means that you must include the empty set, since that's the intersection of two disjoint sets. For example, if you flip a coin, what is the probability of getting both head and tails at the same time? Answer: Zero, since it's an impossible event (corresponding to the empty set in the sample space).

Comment: This answer is spot-on correct, and had been ignorantly down-voted.