# Probability of null set

Tags: probability

We know that the probability of an impossible event is 0. But is the inverse true? That is, if probability of an event is 0, does it necessarily imply the fact that  the event is impossible event? If not, give an example please to understand this concept. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose you choose a real number uniformly at random from the interval $[0,1]$.  The probability that it is exactly $\frac 12$ is $0$, but it is not impossible.  Same sort of observation holds for any continuous distribution.

Comment: Only from a practicality standpoint. Events with probability zero are those for which a procedure can be done over and over forever and is never expected to occur.

Comment: No. See [If $ P(A) = 0 $ is $ A $ a null event?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895772).